# Maintain instance reference

Tags: ruby, oop, reference, composition

i've been battling for two hours with this but can't solve it. Imagine i have this class:

```
class SimpleExpression
attr_writer :value

def initialize(value)
    @value = value
end

def evaluate
    @value
end
```

And then i want to instance it like:

```
exp1 = SimpleExpression.new(true)
exp3 = exp1.not
p exp3.evaluate # This should give me false
exp1.value = false
p exp3.evaluate # This should give me true now
```

I can't really figure out how to maintain the reference for exp1 on exp3, i've tried making a method at SimpleExpression that negates the value and returns self but that clearly does not work since i'd be changing both instances. Thanks. PS: not should be a method in SimpleExpression, i did not write it since i really do not know how to.

Comment: @SebastianPalma: of course, not. That wouldn't respond to `evaluate`

Comment: What is this about "maintaining references"? What do you mean by this and why it's important?

Comment: I edited the code, i had a mistake when doing the puts. I need to (somehow) make a composition between not and the simple expression. As you can see, if i negate exp1, exp1 remains the same (true) but exp3 now should be a "negated" reference to exp1 (false in the example) so when i set exp1 to false, now exp3 should be true.

Comment: @Delsh: ah, I see. Tricky/non-obvious, indeed :)

Comment: `class SimpleExpression` has no matching `end`. The class has no instance method `not`. Please indent each level of code (two spaces being the Ruby convention), starting with `attr_writer :value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was simple "disconnected" negation, the implementation would've been simple:

```
def not
  SimpleExpression.new(!value)
end
```

Here, changing `exp1` does not affect `exp3`.

```
exp1 = SimpleExpression.new(true)
exp3 = exp1.not
p exp3.evaluate # => false
exp1.value = false
p exp3.evaluate # => false
```

But making them "live" requires something a little bit more advanced. I'm thinking, some wrapper objects. Like this, for example:

```
class SimpleExpression
  attr_accessor :value

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def evaluate
    @value
  end

  def not
    NegationWrapper.new(self)
  end

  private

  class NegationWrapper < DelegateClass(self)
    def evaluate
      !__getobj__.evaluate
    end
  end
end

exp1 = SimpleExpression.new(true)
exp3 = exp1.not
p exp3.evaluate # => false
exp1.value = false
p exp3.evaluate # => true
```

Comment: We can forego the wrapper object if `SimpleExpression` can accept another expression in the constructor, not only value. Then it's a matter of a couple of if statements.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I am really curious how it would be if you could add another expression in the constructor, how could this help not to use a wrapper? Thanks!

Comment: @Delsh: take a couple of days and try solve it yourself. Ping me with results and findings. :)

Comment: Will do! Thanks!

Comment: @Delsh: also, when/if you succeed, try adding a few new operations. `and`/`or`, for example. With and without wrappers. Let's see which way generates better code (I'm betting on wrappers)

Comment: Yes, the initial idea was to do it for every (and, or, not) operation! The problem was i could not even make it work for the not so i re-sized the problem. Will try to do it both ways! Thanks